# Add Disqus Plugin on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

how to add Disqus Plugin on localhost wordpress site

After installation it when i login it gives error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUmWO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check in *php.ini* file or with `phpinfo()` function to see, if you have [cURL library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) enabled, if not, enable it.